# Oracle Test Container is throwing "IO Error: Got minus one from a read call"

Tags: docker, oracle12c, testcontainers

I am getting an exception while connection to oracle 12c which is on oracle test container docker.
Oracle 12c docker image is available [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition).

Here is my code:

```
OracleContainer oracleContainer = new OracleContainer("store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1")
    .withUsername("sys")
    .withPassword("Oradoc_db1");
oracleContainer.start();

Class.forName(oracleContainer.getDriverClassName());

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(oracleContainer.getJdbcUrl(), oracleContainer.getUsername(), oracleContainer.getPassword());
System.out.println(connection.toString());
```

Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Got minus one from a read call
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:286)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:287)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
    ... 40 more
```

JDBC URL:
`jdbc:oracle:thin:sys/Oradoc_db1@localhost:32779:xe`

Docker is started successfully, but not able to connect to database.
I have already referred existing solutions regarding this issue, but none of them were related to Oracle Test Container on docker.
Note:

1. Docker is running well and fine.
2. There is no firewall issue. I have already disabled firewall.
3. JDBC Url is also correct.
4. Also tried without using `OracleContainer`. Configured image manually on docker. I got the same error.

Comment: don't use localhost but the docker container name or the gateway ip if the db is running on the host

Comment: It is running on local machine. Oracle 11g is working fine. Only 12c is not working.

Comment: Something is listening on port 32779, but are you sure it's your Oracle Listener? Has that started properly, and on that port? You can get that error if you connect to something else by accident, and it doesn't give the expected respose.

Comment: @AlexPoole This jdbc url is generated by `OracleContainer` and it seems to be valid for oracle 11g and 12c.